# Boot raspberry without SD card slot?

Tags: boot, usb, sd-card

The SD card slot of my Raspberry Pi was broken. I tried to replace (solder) it with one that i bought at eBay but with no success.

I know that a SD slot is required but is there another a way to get my Raspi working without a SD card?

Comment: Removing the SD slot can be difficult. Buy something called "Quick Chip" It has this amazing solder that stays liquied for 30 seconds. That means you do not Burn the PCB by constantly heating it. You might have damaged the PCB for life now :( Can you upload a pic? Did you heat the PCB for extended periods of time. These jobs should not take longer than 1 minute a go to avoid damage!

Answer (score 8):

No, you absolutely positively can **not** boot without SD slot.

You should get another Pi or try to fix the one you have.

Comment: Why can "you absolutely positively…not boot without SD slot"?

Answer (score 4):

My *Raspberry Pi 3* is booting without an SD card.

I flashed the same distro image (LibreElec) onto an SD-card and an USB stick (using Linux and with the `dd` command). After that I've changed the

```
root=/dev/[sdcard]
```

to

```
root=/dev/[usbstick]
```

in `cmdline.txt` in the boot partition from both, SD-card and USB stick.

Finally I've added `program_usb_boot_mode=1` to both `config.txt` files, which enables booting from usb stick.

I don't think that'll help you, however it could be helpful for someone else.

Comment: The official description on how to get an Raspberry Pi 3 to boot from USB,  
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Answer (score 0):

Buy an SMD REWORK STATION and try put it out, clean the zone that being used and then try solder again as it should be, or you just can buy another RPi.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to actually complete the task you started in the first place, to replace the sd card slot.

There is an excellent guide at techunboxed with [instructions](http://www.techunboxed.com/2013/07/how-to-repair-broken-raspberry-pi-sd.html) to fix the SD card slot.

Comment: Generally, one-line answers with a link aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange sites.  Try to give a little more information--if that link ever dies we'd like future users to still find this answer useful.

Also, once you edit your post to add more information, the downvote can actually be changed into an upvote!

Comment: We're [trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538). If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community. (Same rules apply even though the post has not been improved over the last three years.)

Comment: @Ghanima wonderful, thanks for replying to this answer which is over 3 years old with a note about a **new** policy. Surely you have something better to do?

Comment: The problem of link-only posts is not new. Users and mods have played it nice most of the time pointing that issue out using comments only (see @jandjorgensen's comment from Oct '13). More often than not the posters of those answers either ignore the comments or refuse to edit - which is why we try to approach the problem in a new way, as is laid out in detail in above linked meta post. Again, it is not **new** policy just a new way of dealing with it. So why did I post the comment to your answer and not hundreds others? Your post was in the queue of suggested edits and thus came to attention.

Comment: "Again, it is not new policy" you literally said "We're trying a **new** policy with regard to informationless[sic] link-only answers here." at least try to be consistent. A queue of edits to answers older than 3 years? Why bother?

Comment: You're trying to split hairs here. So the first message reads "new policy", ok sorry, but that is not the point. Important is the fact that link-only answers are (and have been) strongly discouraged. That policy has been around and it has been pointed out to you three years ago. You chose to not act on it. Nothing of it has anything to do with the fact that your answer has been edited by someone else and thus put in the review queue of "suggested edits". The edit has been duly rejected. Nonetheless the post was came to my attention and got the comment with respect to our new way of handling.

Comment: @Ghanima literally quoting what you said is not splitting hairs. No consistency from you