# Speech to text conversion for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, software-recommendation, speech-recognition, accessibility

I'm new to this Forum as well as using Raspberry Pi 2 for the first time. I'm currently making a learning device for a blind person. My project requires text-to-speech and speech-to-text conversion to work properly to deliver the pronunciation of words and for the input from the blind user. I'm done with the text-to-speech part and am presently working on the speech-to-text. I'm looking for an Off-line speech synthesizer. Please can you suggest some Software/APIs which I can use for this conversion?

Comment: https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/embedded/raspberrypi2-sr/

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi part of the Stack Exchange network.  I have taken the liberty of editing your question slightly and to choose some tags that I think will work better for your query - should the edit be approved.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/speech-processing-on-the-raspberry-pi/10392 This should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Sly Seven. Thanks a lot Patrick Cook and Dastaan for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "[nano](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/676/36970)" project - or parts thereof - (that soundly beat me in the Christmas Prizes for Best project of 2015) - might be of interest.  It does feature both text-to-speech and speech-to-text if I recall correctly - and [Patrick Cook](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33979/patrick-cook) is a currently active member here.

Once your reputation gets to 20 (*I think*) you might catch him in The Bakery (the Main RPi Chat Room) occasionally which means you can find out how he is progressing with it straight from the horse's mouth...

Comment: I'll give him the final up vote he needs for that 20 rep! :)